# Issue with inheritance in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

Basically I am trying to inherit everything from friction into base (or even the other way round) however, it is not identifying the classes I put in.

base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
   class Base;
}

class Base : public QMainWindow{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
   explicit Base(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~Base();

private:
   Ui::Base *ui;
};
#endif // BASE_H
```

friction.h:

```
#ifndef FRICTION_H
#define FRICTION_H

class Friction : public Base{ // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
  public:
Friction();
};

#endif // FRICTION_H
```

base.cpp

```
#include "friction.h"
#include "base.h"
#include "ui_base.h"

Base::Base(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::Base){
   ui->setupUi(this);
}

Base::~Base(){
   delete ui;
}
```

friction.cpp

```
#include "friction.h"
#include "base.h"
#include "ui_base.h"

Friction::Friction(){
}
```

and finally main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  Base w;
  w.show();

  Friction f;

  return a.exec();
}
```

I receive the error "expected class name before '{' token", I have cut the project down as much as I can and the error still comes up and I really don't know why.

I am fairly new to c++ however I find inheritance not much of an issue on a basic program but upon moving to Qt I couldn't seem to get it working. I have tried numerous things regarding changing the includes etc etc as I am completely oblivious as to why it's not identifying the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If friction inherits Base , than you should put:

```
#include "base.h"
```

in friction.h file , like so:

```
#ifndef FRICTION_H
#define FRICTION_H

#include "base.h"

class Friction : public Base{ // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
  public:
Friction();
};
```

Comment: And, probably, you forgot `Q_OBJECT` in `Friction`

Comment: Oh thank you very much. Sorry for my ignorance I only started c++ 2 days ago.

Comment: @user1 You should learn C++ well before learning Qt.  Qt has strong architecture paradigms based mainly upon what the `moc` can and cannot do, meaning you may learn quite a skewed and narrow view of the language.